# Размещение текста поверх изображения

Tags: html, css

Верстаю макет сайта,  в нем есть блок  с меню в виде картинок и текстом внутри и квадратной обводкой вокруг текста. Не знаю как сделать так, чтобы этот текст вместе с обводкой был поверх картинок. Искал решение на других сайтах, но те примеры решения не совсем то, что нужно. Скриншот блока сайта прилагается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

div:before { /*рамка внутри картики*/
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 35%;
}

h3:before { /*линия над текстом*/
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 40%;
  right: 40%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
h3:before { /*линия под текстом*/
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 40%;
  right: 40%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://matakov.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/2015-11-15_13-52-10-200x300.jpg">
  <h3>Текст</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ещё вариантик

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.block::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.block__outer {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block__inner {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/1920/1080');">
  <div class="block__outer">
    <div class="block__inner">
      <h2 class="block__title">Some text</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Фон выведи через bg-image
обводку через border
обращайся в css через дочерние элементы

Получится примерно так

html

```
<div class=""item>
 men
```

css

```
.

.item{
bg-img: ...;<br>
f-size: ...;<br>
border: 1px solid:#000;<br>
padding: 20px; 10px;
```

Comment: дополните ваши слова примером...